# Markdown-To-PDF indentation via CSS (in obsidian)

Tags: css, pdf, markdown, obsidian

I use Obsidian (*Markdown Editor*), where one can export markdown to pdf.
For this **CSS Snippets** can be supplied to be applied in the convertion.

I want to indent all headers and following paragraphs based on the header level
(for example:)

```
h1 Heading
paragraph
  h2 Heading
  paragraph
  paragraph
      h4 Heading
      paragraph
    h3 Heading
    paragraph
```

Sadly (as far as I know) CSS-classes **cannot easily** be used in this case (=obsidian).
(It would be a pain to manually apply)

My current solution (crafted from tutorials, snippeds and, ofc, stackoverflow);

```
h6,
h6 ~ *{
  margin-left: 100px;
}

h5,
h5 ~ *:not(h6,h6 ~ *){
  margin-left:  80px;
}

h4,
h4 ~ *:not(h6,h6 ~ *):not(h5,h5 ~ *){
  margin-left:  60px;
}

h3,
h3 ~ *:not(h6,h6 ~ *):not(h5,h5 ~ *):not(h4,h4 ~ *){
  margin-left:  40px;
}

h2,
h2 ~ *:not(h6,h6 ~ *):not(h5,h5 ~ *):not(h4,h4 ~ *):not(h3,h3 ~ *){
  margin-left:  20px;
}

h1,
h1 ~ *:not(h6,h6 ~ *):not(h5,h5 ~ *):not(h4,h4 ~ *):not(h3,h3 ~ *):not(h2,h2 ~ *){
  margin-left:  0px;
}
```

**The problem with this**:
It only kinda works, because it indents correctly as long as there isnt a *higher level heading* after a *lower level heading*
(for example: this is what my code would **wrongly** produce)

```
h1
  h2
    h3
    h2 <- Error
```

I do know **why** my code does not work, but sadly i do not really know how to **fix** it

---

One of my already discarded solutions was

```
.HyperMD-header-1 ~ .cm-line, /* Editing View */
.el-h1 ~ * /* Reading View */
{
    text-indent: 1.5em;
}

.HyperMD-header-2 ~ .cm-line, /* Editing View */
.el-h2 ~ * /* Reading View */
{
    text-indent: 3em;
}

.HyperMD-header-3 ~ .cm-line, /* Editing View */
.el-h3 ~ * /* Reading View */
{
    text-indent: 4.5em;
}

.HyperMD-header-4 ~ .cm-line, /* Editing View */
.el-h4 ~ * /* Reading View */
{
    text-indent: 6em;
}

.HyperMD-header-5 ~ .cm-line, /* Editing View */
.el-h5 ~ * /* Reading View */
{
    text-indent: 7.5em;
}
```

But this only worked in obsidians editing view, and i could not figure out what exactly the code does sooo... i discarded it
(idk eventually it helps)

---

I really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Not sure whether obsidian has something similar to [pandoc's `--section-divs` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options#option--section-divs[) which you could style like `section { margin-left: 1em; }`

Comment: @mb21
I investigated this idea. Sadly, this seems not to be the case. Every new-line in Obsidian is its own div and there isnt an option for such (cool) section-divs.

The only option to solve the problem like this, would be to use obsidians Callouts, which are textboxes.
Then the content of those would be wrapped inside the textbox div... but this seems, like per hand-div-ing, very tiresome and crude :( .

As of now, it looks like only some css wizardry would fix this.
Or a full-blown Obsidian plugin :/ .

But thank you !